# for in loop in jsx got unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const ProfileDetail = ({user}) => (
  <Card className="container">
    {for (let key in user) {
        if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          <li>{key}: {user[key]}</li>
        }
    }}
  </Card>
);
```

Can't I do loop like this in jxs? Can't do it outside of render method because this is a stateless component.

What's wrong with above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of a `{...}` [must be an *expression*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx). `for` is a *statement*.

In this case, you could use `Object.keys` to do it all in a single outermost expression (it also does the "own" property check for you):

```
const ProfileDetail = ({user}) => (
  <Card className="container">
    {Object.keys(user).map(key => <li>{key}: {user[key]}</li>)}
  </Card>
);
```

If you prefer the `for` loop, though, just make the function a verbose arrow rather than a concise one, build the items up in an array, and then use them in the JSX:

```
const ProfileDetail = ({user}) => {
  const items = [];
  for (let key in user) {
    if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      items.push(<li>{key}: {user[key]}</li>);
    }
  }
  return <Card className="container">{items}</Card>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside JSX we can't use `if-else/switch/for`, but you can call a function and inside that you can use all these. Check the [DOC](http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html).

Inside `Stateless Functional Component` also you can write `function`, like this:

```
 const ProfileDetail = ({user}) => {
    var createList = function(){
       let a = [];
       for (let key in user) {
          if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            a.push(<li key={key}>{key}: {user[key]}</li>)
          } 
       }
       return a;
    }
    return (
       <Card className="container">
            {createList()}
      </Card>
   ) 
};
```

But instead of that you can use map it will be more easy, like this:

```
const ProfileDetail = ({user}) => (
  <Card className="container">
    {Object.keys(user).map((el,i) => <li key={i}>{el}: {user[el]}</li>)}
  </Card>
);
```

**Suggestion**:

**1.** When using `for` loop with `object`, variable will represent each key of the `object` so checking `user.hasOwnProperty(key)` i think is not required.

**2.** `For loop` will not return anything, you need to use some variable to push the `ui-items` in that, then return that variable after `loop`. Use `map` it will be easy as well as it will do the same task in less lines and you don't need a extra variable also.

Check this example:

```js
let user = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5};
const ProfileDetail = ({user}) => {
    var createList = function(){
       let a = [];
       for (let key in user) {
          a.push(<li>{key}: {user[key]}</li>)
       }
       return a;
    }
    return (
       <ul>
           {createList()}
           
           ------By using map------
           {
             Object.keys(user).map(el => <li key={el}>{el}: {user[el]} </li>)
           }
           
      </ul>
   ) 
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProfileDetail user={user}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```